# QT: Program crash on glDrawElements()

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, crash

I wanted to load a model into OpenGL with Assimp.

I am using QT as my framework that provides me with the functions needed.

Baiscally, my program crashes at Mesh::DrawMesh at gl.glDrawElements()...

I bet it has to do with one of my allocations but I don't know.

I am sure the model is loaded correctly because I compared the loaded results ;)

So here I post the initialize function that basically sets up the buffers etc. for that mesh. I think that maybe something went wrong there:

```
void Mesh::initialize()
{

vao->create();
vbo->create();
ebo->create();

vao->bind();

    vbo->bind(); //glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo); // Bind vbo
    vbo->setUsagePattern(QOpenGLBuffer::StaticDraw);
    vbo->allocate(vertices.data(),vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex)); //glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex), vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW); //Allocates space in bytes


    ebo->bind(); //glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
    ebo->setUsagePattern(QOpenGLBuffer::StaticDraw);
    ebo->allocate(indices.data(),indices.size()*sizeof(GLuint)); //glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(GLuint), indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW); //Allocates space in bytes

    program->enableAttributeArray(0); //glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); //On layout = 0
    program->setAttributeBuffer(0,GL_FLOAT,0,sizeof(Vertex));//glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,sizeof(Vertex),0); // Stride is sizeof(Vertex) ofc, offset is 0 because we want to access Position

    program->enableAttributeArray(1); //glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    program->setAttributeBuffer(1,GL_FLOAT,offsetof(Vertex,Normal),3,sizeof(Vertex)); //glVertexAttribPointer(1,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*) offsetof(Vertex, Normal));

    program->enableAttributeArray(2);
    program->setAttributeBuffer(2,GL_FLOAT,offsetof(Vertex,TextCoords),2,sizeof(Vertex));//glVertexAttribPointer(2,2,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*) offsetof(Vertex, TextCoords));

vao->release();

}
```

This is my Draw method that gets called when the program is bound:

```
void Mesh::DrawMesh(QOpenGLFunctions_3_3_Core& gl)
{
    vao->bind();
    qDebug() << vertices.size();
    gl.glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(),GL_UNSIGNED_INT,0);
    vao->release();
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location=0) in vec3 position;
layout(location=1) in vec3 normal;
layout(location=2) in vec2 textCoords;

uniform mat4 MVP;

out vec4 color;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position= MVP*vec4(position,1);
    color = vec4(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5);
}
```

InitializeGL function of my QOpenGLWidget:

```
void RenderingWindow::initializeGL()
{ 
this->initializeOpenGLFunctions();
program.create();
program.addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, ":/testvert.vert"    );
program.addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, ":/testfrag.frag");
program.link();
program.bind();

this->glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

Camera::instance().LookAt(0,0,10, 0,0,0 ,0,1,0);

model.SetProgram(&program);
model.LoadModel(*this, "C:/Users/TestCube.fbx");
program.release();

}
```

This is my Vertex struct:

```
struct Vertex
{
    QVector3D Position;
    QVector3D Normal;
    QVector2D TextCoords;
};
```

Comment: The first `setAttributeBuffer` is visibly wrong. Where do you create `vbo` and `ebo`?

Comment: Yes, I didn't see that...
It works. Omg, no crashing... thanks buddy

Comment: You know, after a while of staring those mistakes aren't clear anymore.